# how do you assign an array for a default constructor?

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++ and I'm having issues with making a class.

So I have this pad class and it has `double` inputs of the x and y coordinates for the sides of the pad. To elaborate, say you had a pad of 2cmx2cm it would have `pad({0.0,2.0},{0.0,2.0})`. I wanted to set the default constructor to be a pad of 0x0.

```
class pad {
   public:
    double xcor[2] = {0, 0};
    double ycor[2] = {0, 0};
    double charge = 0;
    pad() = default;  // put this for now to work on code that works with the
                      // pad object

    pad(double xcord[], double ycord[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            xcor[i] = xcord[i];
            ycor[i] = ycord[i];
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: *I wanted to set the default constructor to be a pad of 0x0.* You've already done that by using `double xcor[2]={0,0};` and `double ycor[2]={0,0};`

Comment: Just don't use `double xcor[2]`. If you write in C++, you have `std::array<double, 2>`. Or, considering the description of your problem, just define a `struct Point { double x; double y; };` and define your pad with 2 points `class Pad { Point lowerLeft; Point upperRight; };`

Answer (score 5):

What you did in lines such as:

```
double xcor[2]={0,0};
```

is called a [**default member initializer**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).

As you can see in the link, it is setting the value of the data member before running the body of the constructor.
In your case it will initialize the `xcor`, `ycor` etc. before invoking the default constructor which will not modify them. You will be left with the values as you wanted.

**Side notes:**

1. If you use a [**member initializer list**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), it has precedence over the default member initializer:

> If a non-static data member has a default member initializer and also
> appears in a member initializer list, then the member initializer is
> used and the default member initializer is ignored

2. I agree with the advice in the comments above to use [**`std::array`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of a C style array.

Answer (score 3):

You are making things more complex than they need to. `pad` is an aggregate type and you can simply use aggregate initialization:

```
class pad {
public:

    double xcor[2]={0,0};
    double ycor[2]={0,0};
    double charge=0;
};

pad pad0{};
pad pad1{{1,2}};
pad pad2{{1,2}, {3,4}};
pad pad3{{1,2}, {3,4}, 23};
```

But if you do want to have more complex constructors then do use `std::array` instead of C-style arrays as they follow value semantics and passing them around as arguments to functions comes naturally. Passing C-sytle arrays has a horrible syntax and is never safe from accidental errors.